# Google Calendar API event location

Tags: grails, groovy, google-calendar-api

I inherited some Groovy code that looks like it was built using the v2 Google calendar API. It's essentially getting a list of all the events from a calendar and building a display screen. Previously, it was using a URL like:

```
/full?alt=json&max-results=25&orderby=starttime&sortorder=ascending&futureevents=true&end-max=" + dateEnd
```

I know that the /full URL is deprecated, so I replaced that with /basic and provided the private URL to one of my calendars, so it looks like:

```
/basic?alt=json&max-results=25&orderby=starttime&sortorder=ascending&futureevents=true&end-max=" + dateEnd
```

That gets the data back. However, when parsing the data they are trying to get the location of each event using the gd$where attribute off of each feed entry. As far as I can tell, the gd$where attribute is only available at the base calendar level now, and I don't see an attribute that comes back that I can use to pull the location of the event.

Here's a short snippet of the code they currently have.

```
data.feed.entry.each{ event ->

        def eventResponse = [
                title: '',
                start: '',
                end: '',
                updated: '',
                description: '',
                location:'',
                attendees: []
        ]

        eventResponse.title = event.title.$t
        eventResponse.description = event.content.$t
        eventResponse.location = event.gd$where[0].valueString
        eventResponse.start = event.gd$when[0].startTime
        eventResponse.end = event.gd$when[0].endTime
        eventResponse.updated = event.updated.$t
```

Can I no longer use the URL to the calendar to get this information or am I just missing something? This is my first time using the Google Calendar functionality so I'm completely green here.

Comment: May I ask how did you solve the problem? I'm having a similar issue! trying to get it to work with /basic but it fails (forever pending) with I run the following code:

Comment: `new Event( start: new LocalDateTime(entry.getTimes().get(0).getStartTime().getValue(), ))`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to investigate using the [updated API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) for Google Calendars. The reason for my suggesting this is because the [Event representation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events) contains the location information:

```
{
  "kind": "calendar#event",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": string,
  "status": string,
  "htmlLink": string,
  "created": datetime,
  "updated": datetime,
  "summary": string,
  "description": string,
  "location": string,
  ...
}
```

Comment: I came across a case similar to OP did. Seems the `location` key is optional and is not added when the event is created with an empty location.